# Magento, enabling DHL, "Site Id is wrong"

Tags: magento

We have just tried to enable DHL shipping method on our Magento backend, and for some reason the mentioned "Site Id is wrong" error keeps coming up. We have checked and re-checked that our information is correct, and have tried searching for similar problems, but can't find any that match or have been answered. After digging up through the logs, this is what we have found:

```
(   
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd "><GetQuote xmlns=""><Request><ServiceHeader><SiteID>*site id*</SiteID><Password>*password*</Password></ServiceHeader></Request><From><CountryCode>EE</CountryCode><Postalcode>11911</Postalcode><City>Tallinn</City></From><BkgDetails><PaymentCountryCode>EE</PaymentCountryCode><Date>2013-03-04</Date><ReadyTime>PT48H00M</ReadyTime><DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit><WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit><Pieces xmlns=""><Piece xmlns=""><PieceID>1</PieceID><Weight>1.5</Weight></Piece></Pieces><PaymentAccountNumber>323080462</PaymentAccountNumber><IsDutiable>Y</IsDutiable></BkgDetails><To><CountryCode>SG</CountryCode><Postalcode>510583</Postalcode><City>Singapore</City></To><Dutiable><DeclaredCurrency>EUR</DeclaredCurrency><DeclaredValue>166.25</DeclaredValue></Dutiable></GetQuote></p:DCTRequest>

    [result] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><res:ErrorResponse xmlns:res='http://www.dhl.com' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation= 'http://www.dhl.com err-res.xsd'>
    <Response>
        <ServiceHeader>
            <MessageTime>2013-03-03T22:58:48+00:00</MessageTime>
            <SiteID>*site id*</SiteID>
            <Password>*site id*</Password>
        </ServiceHeader>
        <Status>
            <ActionStatus>Error</ActionStatus>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionCode>100</ConditionCode>
                <ConditionData>Validation Failure:Site Id is wrong</ConditionData>
            </Condition>
        </Status>
    </Response></res:ErrorResponse>
    [__pid] => 11937
)

2013-03-04T00:58:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(   
    [100] => Error #100 : Validation Failure:Site Id is wrong
    [__pid] => 11937
)
```

If you read through that carefully, the code later seems to send the site id as the site id and password for some reason (and again, we have checked that the site id and password have been put in correctly in the configuration).

Has anyone encountered similar problems or know where we could look for a fix?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: have you ever got this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

i had a phone-call with DHL: you need to create anoter Site-Account in the DHL Backend and use those credentials as a Login - works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Have you applied for developer credentials with DHL? Or are you using the username & password you created to log into a regular customer account on DHL's website? I had the same issue you're describing and even after DHL sent me a unique siteID & password (you have to fill out a form and request access to their xml services) I was still getting the 'Site Id is wrong' error. What worked for me was leaving the 'Account Number' field blank (in Magento backend under Shipping Options > DHL).